# Dlib Element Specific Operations

Tags: c++, machine-learning, dlib

Using the dlib library how do you do element specific operations? E.g.

A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

Instead of it going A*A, can I get it to square the elements of the matrix so that the answer would be

ans = [1 4 9; 16 25 36]

In matlab you could simply go A.^2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointwise_multiply(), which is in the library "matrix.h".
e.g.

```
matrix<double> A(3,2);
A = 1,    2,
    3,    4,
    5,    6;

matrix<double> B(3,2);
B = 1,    2,
    3,    4,
    5,    6;

matrix<double> answer = pointwise_multiply(A,B);
```

Or alternatively

```
matrix<double> answer = squared(A);
```